# JSON import - Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to import JSON via API into Google sheets but get the error

`Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Here is my code

```
function importRank(){
  url = 'https://public-api.solscan.io/token/holders?tokenAddress=sinjBMHhAuvywW3o87uXHswuRXb3c7TfqgAdocedtDj&offset=0&limit=max'
  var json = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText())
  var data = json.data.owner
  var data2 = json.data.rank
  var data3 = json.data.total
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('WalletRank')
  sh.getRange(2,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data)
  sh.getRange(2,2,data2.length,data2[0].length).setValues(data2)
  sh.getRange(2,3,data3.length,data3[0].length).setValues(data3)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas)

Comment: json.data is not a parent, json.data is an array

Comment: You want to retrieve all 24159 data from the API and put them to the Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes - OR look up a value in my spreadsheet and return that row from the API

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand `OR look up a value in my spreadsheet and return that row from the API`. But I understood that your issue has already been resolved. I'm glad about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function importRank(){
  url = 'https://public-api.solscan.io/token/holders?tokenAddress=sinjBMHhAuvywW3o87uXHswuRXb3c7TfqgAdocedtDj&offset=0&limit=max'
  var json = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText())
  var data=[]
  Logger.log(json.total)
  json.data.forEach(function(x){
    data.push([x.owner,x.rank,x.amount])
  })
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('WalletRank')
  sh.getRange(2,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data)
  sh.getRange(2,4).setValue(json.total)
}
```

[image]

### Explanation

the structure is as follows

```
{"data":[
{"address":"__________","amount":________,"decimals":__,"owner":"___","rank":_},
...
],"total":_____}
```

that means that data is an array `[]` of multi elements which contains each of them `{}` address, amount, decimals, owner and rank

### Reference

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thank you! Almost perfect - but there are 2 issues:

1. Data import is limited to 5000 rows, whereas the JSON has over 20K rows. I suspect this is a pagination issue.
2. Missing data for "total" which should appear in cell D2.

Comment: In fact given the pagination issues it might be easier to log the JSON data and then perform a lookup of a given "owner" (found in cell Index!C9 in my sheet) for the corresponding"rank".

Comment: total can be fetch by `json.total` I have amended my answer

Comment: if you can give me url other pages i can put them all together

Comment: That is very helpful thankyou! There are no other URLs - if you look at the API data at that URL in a browser you will see it has +20K rows.

Comment: I have downloaded the file with IE, Edge, and Chrome, and the last item is the rank 5000 owner  FmWtbvHAnwpnFytVnxagDa3vG1HZdyM9DeQ65DkJB4LG. I can't see anything else. Please provide a screenshot in the request.

Comment: even if you try to fetch with &offset=0&limit=20000 parameters, the site will return only 5000

Comment: Thank you  - you are correct!